# Do I use a singular or plural verb?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I had this MCQ question one day when I was studying for my exams:

> All the proceeds from the fund-raising event _________ going to be donated to charity.

The two MCQ options that I debated on was 
1) is 
2) are

I chose *are*, which was the incorrect answer, unfortunately. However, I am puzzled on why *is* is the correct answer. According to [here](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/proceeds.html), it says that **proceeds are plural nouns** (and the *are* in that was corrected by Grammarly) and *plural nouns should be used with a plural verb*, which is *are*.

But, according to [here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1OKWM_enSG795SG795&sxsrf=ALeKk03WMGHftvCSYl-wOwTuoBHkAIFKPg%3A1589343641007&ei=mXW7XrYQr9PPuw_Hh4rQDw&q=is%20proceeds%20countable%20or%20uncountable&oq=is&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEIMBMgUIABCDATICCAAyBQgAEIMBMgIIADoECAAQRzoECAAQQ1CephpYxqcaYOG5GmgAcAF4AIABWYgBnwGSAQEymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab), proceeds (money) is uncountable and that [uncountable nouns must be used with a singular verb](https://www.ef.sg/english-resources/english-grammar/countable-and-uncountable-nouns/), which is *is*.

Which is correct?

Comment: *… **The proceeds** … **are** …* is correct. The subject of the verb is **not** *the fund-raising event* but **the proceeds** *[from the fundraising event]*.

Comment: **The man** *[who walked across the street, ate a chocolate sundae, and gave 3 apples to 4 children]* **was** tall.

Comment: @JasonBassford My dispute was that I didn't know whether I should use _is_ or _are_ with proceeds as the subject

Comment: Ah! [*Proceeds*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceeds) is a plural noun. It's uncountable, but it still take a plural form.

Comment: @JasonBassford But my teacher said that it was _is_...

Comment: Your teacher was wrong. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in comments under the question, it was clear that *proceeds* was the subject of the sentence, but it wasn't clear if the verb that goes with it should be singular or plural.

Why? Because it is uncountable, and it was assumed that all uncountable nouns are singular.

---

This is true in general. However, like most things in English, there are always exceptions.

[*Proceeds*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceeds) ***is*** an uncountable noun. But it's also the exception to the general rule, and it actually has a plural form:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *plural noun*
>   **1** : the total amount brought in
>       // the *proceeds* of a sale
>   **2** : the net amount received (as for a check or from an insurance settlement) after deduction of any discount or charges

---

As such:

> All **the proceeds** from the fund-raising event ***are*** going to be donated to charity.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :) I will mark this as correct after I check again with my teachers